# How can I make custom pagination in splidejs

Tags: css, slider, splidejs

I am trying to achieve this number pagination on right side using splidejs slider but unable to do it.
[image]

What I have so far is this.
[image]

and here is my custom pagination code for this

```
{
#testimonial-splide .splide__pagination
   {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: auto;
    right: -5.5em;
    transform: translateY(50%);
   }
#testimonial-splide .splide__pagination__page {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    transition: transform .2s linear;
     border: 2px solid var(--darkblue);
    opacity: 1;
    // color: var(--red);
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #999;
    font-family: "Abril Fatface", serif;  
}
#testimonial-splide .splide__pagination__page.is-active {
    background: var(--red);
    border: 2px solid var(--red);
}
}
```

Comment: Please add more details and a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use default button pagination, you have to implement it by using [APIs](https://splidejs.com/guides/apis/).

The easiest way is by adding `EventListener` to your own custom pagination pages and use `go(control, wait = true)` method to navigate the slides.

Or you can use `sync(splide)` method if you want to make another slider as a custom pagination.

**Edit:**

With recently released [Splide v3](https://splidejs.com/guides/version3/), it's now easier to create your own [custom pagination](https://splidejs.com/guides/pagination/#custom-pagination). Although it's not as customizable as using API, it's better for a simple style change.